# How do I stick these divs together?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to stick 3 divs up but I can't. I don't know whats wrong.

Here is a [screenshot](http://i1204.photobucket.com/albums/bb409/bendaggers/help-1.png).

**HTML**

```php
<div id="container">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            <p class="postmetadata">
                <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="post"><h2><?php _e('Not Found'); ?></h2></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.post{
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  background-image: url(images/toppost.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}


.post h2{
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 0 0px 0px;
}

.entry{
  background-image:url(images/ContentBG.png);
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding:0 5px !important;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.postmetadata {
  clear: both;
  background-image: url(images/post-footer.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:118px;
  padding:0 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML code? Is there a </h2> tag missing?

Comment: Please post the final markup, rather than the intermediate script

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to remove the margins from the elements inside those DIVs. E.g. if the last element in your first DIV has a margin-bottom, it will 'leak out' and cause the gaps. Same goes for the first element in your second DIV, etc.

Try creating this document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    /*p, h2 { margin: 0; }*/
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="background-color: #eee;"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: #ddd;"><p>Dolor sit amet</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and compare what happens when you uncomment the style. Note that the background-colors are there so you can visualise the DIVs.

Comment: I'm sorry bobby, but in English please. I'm just a self pity newbie in css. what do you mean by that? by the way, its a wordpress index file and the screen shot shows each post container, so if i have 5 post, i'll be seeing 5 boxes like that (just few description, might help you picture out)

Comment: OK, say you have two DIVs, one after the other, each containing a single paragraph (I know your case is different, but the concept is the same). By default, those paragraphs have a margin (both top and bottom). Due to some fairly obscure rules in the CSS spec, those margins will appear to 'leak out' of the containing DIVs, causing a gap between them. To remove it, you need to remove the bottom margin from the first P and the top margin from the second. If that's still not clear, I'll try to put an example up somewhere online.

Comment: i think i get what you are saying. But the problem is, when i put margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; nothing will happen and still the same results.

Comment: Bobby, you pulled it! thank you very much! I've been stuck staring blankly in front of my monitor with this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Divs are block elements so you need to remove the margin-height from the them as well, with margin-height: 0px;

Comment: DIVs have zero margin by default